# How to run a Datastore GQL query in Golang?

Tags: go, google-cloud-datastore, gql

I have the following query in GQL:

`"SELECT * FROM Task WHERE Uuid = \"FOOBAR\" ORDER BY CreateTimeMs DESC LIMIT 1"`

How can I directly run this query in Golang?

`query := datastore.NewQuery("SELECT * FROM Task WHERE Uuid = \"FOOBAR\" ORDER BY CreateTimeMs DESC LIMIT 1")` seems to be incorrect.

**UPDATE:**
I am very aware of the [Query types](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/datastore/reference#Query). The thing is that I would like to use GQL directly instead of translating them into Query types.

Comment: What error do you get? Or what other evidence do you have that it's incorrect?

Comment: cannot use `"SELECT * FROM Task WHERE Uuid = \"foobar\" ORDER BY CreateTimeMs DESC LIMIT 1" (type string) as type *"cloud.google.com/go/datastore".Query in argument to client.Run`. This makes sense, the point is more, that I don't know which function to use for GQL queries...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was searching to solve exactly the same problem when I came across this note in the [GQL documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/gql_reference):

> **Note:** Google Cloud Client Library for Java and Google Cloud Client Library for Ruby support GQL, but other Google Cloud client libraries do not.

So that's a no-go ...

However, it should be feasible to implement it over the [REST api projects.runQuery](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects/runQuery) but then you have to unmarshal the result into structs by yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the info Wim

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Query](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/datastore/reference#Query) type documentation, from looking at its methods and reading their respective documentation you should be able to understand how to translate your SQL into `datastore.Query` specific method calls.

For example your sql can be written as:

```
q := datastore.NewQuery("Task").Filter("Uuid =", "FOOBAR").Order("-CreateTimeMs").Limit(1)
```

This just builds your Query value, to get the actual result you need to [run](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/datastore/reference#Query.Run) the query to get an [iterator](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/datastore/reference#Iterator) whose [Next method](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/datastore/reference#Iterator.Next) can be used to read the result.

If you want to avoid the run-iterate-next dance you can use the [GetAll](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/datastore/reference#Query.GetAll) query method.

```
var tt = []*Task{}
q := datastore.NewQuery("Task").Filter("Uuid =", "FOOBAR").Order("-CreateTimeMs").Limit(1)
if _, err := q.GetAll(tt); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
log.Println(tt[0]) // your task
```

Read more here:

- [Datastore Queries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/datastore/queries)
- [Retrieving query results](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/datastore/retrieving-query-results)
- [Query Restrictions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/datastore/query-restrictions)
- [Query Cursors](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/datastore/query-cursors)

Comment: Thanks @mkoprive, I'm aware of this. The thing is, I have a bunch of GQL queries that I would like to run directly. But, I will accept this answer because for whatever reason the friendly Go community already started downvoting this question.

Comment: I'm sorry I've totally misunderstood your question. I did a quick search and it seems to me that you're stuck with the `Query` type, I can't find anything on `GQL` in the Go specific documentation on appengine.

Comment: No worries, thanks. An upvote to 0 would be appreciated though :-)

Comment: There you go, just to be clear it wasn't me who downvoted ;).

Comment: o, oops, haha. Thanks though ;-)